# Grouping file paths in a Microsoft SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, select

I have a table with a list of folders that looks like this:

```
Path                    Size
C:\ParentFolder\A       123
C:\ParentFolder\A\B     442434
C:\ParentFolder\A\B\C   13413412
C:\ParentFolder\D       2422341234
C:\ParentFolder\D\E     3342
C:\ParentFolder\D\E\F   2
C:\ParentFolder\D\E\G   2
...
```

I'm looking for some combination of SUM, GROUP BY, and PATINDEX/LTRIM/SUBSTRING/etc. which would give me back this:

```
Path                    SumSize
C:\ParentFolder\A       13855969
C:\ParentFolder\D       2422344580
...
```

C:\ParentFolder is a known prefix, but A,D,etc. are variable folder names. Do I need to write a function to accomplish that or can I use some combination of string functions?

Comment: What sql-version are you using?

Comment: One level down? Yes, I want to summarize A and everything under A. D and everything under D and nothing else. The trick is I don't know what A and D are until runtime.
Version? SQL 2008R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your testing set,

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (Folder varchar(100) not null, Size bigint not null)

INSERT #MyTable values
  ('C:\ParentFolder\A'     ,  123)
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\A\B'   ,  442434)
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\A\B\C' ,  13413412)
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\D'     ,  2422341234)
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\D\E'   ,  3342)
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\D\E\F' ,  2)
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\D\E\G' ,  2)
```

you'd first determine what folders you want to summarize. I do so here by loading them into a temp table:

```
DECLARE @Targets table (Folder varchar(100) not null)
INSERT @Targets values
  ('C:\ParentFolder\A')
 ,('C:\ParentFolder\D')
```

From here it's easy, using the like clause:

```
SELECT ta.Folder, sum(Size) TotalSize
 from @Targets ta
  left outer join #MyTable mt
   on mt.Folder like ta.Folder + '%'
 group by ta.Folder
```

Complications may ensue if your folders contain reserved characters used by the `like` clause: `% _ ] [` and a few others.

Comment: I think it will give worg result due to the duplication when using  `like` operator

Comment: This solution was the cleanest. The only adjustment I had to make was change 
    INSERT @Targets values
    ('C:\ParentFolder\A')
     ,('C:\ParentFolder\D')

Into a dynamic query that would discover the folders at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.Path, sum(Size) as SumSize
from MyTable m
inner join (
    select Path
    from MyTable 
    where charindex('\', Path, len('C:\ParentFolder\') + 1) = 0 
) r on charindex(r.Path, m.Path, 0) = 1
group by r.Path
```

[SQL Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d30b6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is always an entry for the highest level dir (i.e if there is a `c:\xxx\yyy\zzz` there will always be a `c:\xxx\yyy` how about

```
;with roots (root) as (
     select distinct
        path + '\' 
     from 
        thetable
     where 
        --only include paths with 2 x \
        len(path) - 2 = len(replace(path, '\', '')) 
)
select
    roots.root,
    sum(thetable.size)
from 
    roots
inner join 
    thetable on left(thetable.path + '\', len(roots.root)) = roots.root 
group by
    roots.root
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select path, (select sum(Size) 
               from Paths p2 where p2.Path like p1.Path+'%') as total
 from Paths p1
 where charIndex('\',Path, len('C:\ParentFolder\')+1) = 0
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that immediate children names will only be one character long, *"but A,D,etc. are variable folder names."*

Answer (score 0):

--If the folder name is always one character

```
select 
LEFT(folder,CHARINDEX('r\',folder)+2) as folder_group
,SUM(size) as sumsize
from #mytable
GROUP BY
LEFT(folder,CHARINDEX('r\',folder)+2)
```

--If the folder name has a variable length

```
select 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder)+1)+1) = 0 THEN folder
    ELSE LEFT(folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder)+1)+1) -1) END AS folder_group
,SUM(size) as sumsize
from #mytable
GROUP BY
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder)+1)+1) = 0 THEN folder
    ELSE LEFT(folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder,CHARINDEX('\',folder)+1)+1) -1) END
```